# Where discarded messages are going in SpringIntegration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have a discard channel for some filters and aggregators, but we have seen that discard channel is a regular direct channel.

So, where those discarded messages go ? to DLQ ?

And also, do they live forever there ? Because we are struggling with memory consumption and we would like those messages to be deleted (garbage collected ) as soon they arrive to the DLQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if Spring Integration is based on the Messaging concepts, it is just a tool to build integration solutions. It isn't a Broker and therefore doesn't provide out-of-the-box state management like queue persistence and DLQ.

You are correct, the `discardChannel` is just a `MessageChannel` and you can inject any implementation there and do some desired logic in the discard flow on that channel. Sending to DLQ is already your particular use-case and you really should do that manually. There is nothing specific for Spring Integration on that discard channel. And if it is just regular `QueueChannel` without any poller on the matter, you really end up once with the `OOM` because messages are stored in the memory forever.

Comment: Ohhh, this is what is happening to us OOM.

Comment: And our Discard Channel is a regular Direct Channel with no one consuming from it. 
**So what do we have to do to avoid OOM ?** We would like to directly delete (kill) those messages in the Discard Channel as they arrive.

Comment: Well, that isn't possible to send to empty (without subscribers) `DirectChannel` and don't have `Dispatcher has no subscribers` exception. I think there is something else there causing that `OOM`. If you are not interested in the discarded messages at all, you really don't  need to specify `discardChannel` on the `filter` or use `nullChannel`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-special-channels